# How can I scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler, phantomjs

I am trying to scrape a [website](http://www.bdtong.co.kr/index.php?c_category=C02) but I don't get some of the elements, because these elements are dynamically created.

I use the cheerio in node.js and My code is below.

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var url = "http://www.bdtong.co.kr/index.php?c_category=C02";

request(url, function (err, res, html) {
    var $ = cheerio.load(html);
    $('.listMain > li').each(function () {
        console.log($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
    });
});
```

This code returns empty response, because when the page is loaded, the `<ul id="store_list" class="listMain">` is empty.

The content has not been appended yet.

How can I get these elements using node.js? How can I scrape pages with dynamic content?

Comment: use phantom.js a headless browser, it will load and render the page. you can access different elements on the page using its javascript API.

Comment: Thanks Safi! But Could you give me a code snippet or some reference with this case?

Comment: @Safi Phantom is deprecated and no longer maintained, so I suggest deleting the comment and flagging this one for removal as well if you don't mind.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Here you go;

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create(function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {
    var url = "http://www.bdtong.co.kr/index.php?c_category=C02";
    page.open(url, function() {
      page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
        page.evaluate(function() {
          $('.listMain > li').each(function () {
            console.log($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
          });
        }, function(){
          ph.exit()
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: This works fine!! Thank you very much. But I have another question. This page append child using scroll down. So I have to know when the end of that group to be attached. May be above code declare callback (function() { ph.exit() } but phantom is not terminated and retain cursor!!

Comment: @Safi I copied and tried the above code but nothing happens. Can you please help me. I run node file.js and it comes to the next line.

Comment: where exactly in this code is the logic to wait for ajax to finish loading? I don't understand how phantom would know.

Comment: phantom: ⚠️  **This package has been deprecated** ⚠️  This package is no longer maintained. You might want to try using puppeteer instead

Comment: @1mike12 you can await a setTimeout promise after opening the page, or Phantom's waitFor can help you validate that a certain condition is true inside the page

Answer (score 23):

Check out [GoogleChrome/puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer)

> Headless Chrome Node API

It makes scraping pretty trivial. The following example will scrape the headline over at [npmjs.com](http://npmjs.com)

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  await page.goto('https://www.npmjs.com/');

  const textContent = await page.evaluate(() => {
    return document.querySelector('body').textContent
  });

  console.log(textContent); /* No Problem Mate */

  browser.close();
})();
```

[`evaluate`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) will allow for the inspection of the dynamic element as this will run scripts on the page.

Comment: Good choice, accounting, this [announcement](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/phantomjs/9aI5d-LDuNE)

Comment: I read some articles, may I say that puppeteer runs on server (node.js) not on client side (in browser)?

Comment: @user10838321 Your understanding is correct--Puppeteer runs on the server in Node.

Answer (score 12):

Use the new npm module [x-ray](https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray), with a pluggable web driver [x-ray-phantom](https://github.com/lapwinglabs/x-ray-phantom).

Examples in the pages above, but here's how to do dynamic scraping:

```
var phantom = require('x-ray-phantom');
var Xray = require('x-ray');

var x = Xray()
  .driver(phantom());

x('http://google.com', 'title')(function(err, str) {
  if (err) return done(err);
  assert.equal('Google', str);
  done();
})
```

Comment: Are you running this program as `node google_xray_code.js` or as `phantomjs  google_xray_code.js` ??  In its current form, phantomjs is not a node module..

Comment: @zipzit phantom is not a node module; it's a driver that you install externally and export the path of if you wish to use it with x-ray.

Comment: what makes this dynamic? the page title of google.com is static no?

Comment: phantom stderr: 'phantomjs' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

C:\Projects\Dealbuilder1One\node_modules\nightmare\lib\index.js:284
    throw err;
    ^

Comment: I tried with this, x-ray works perectly on static website. But for dynamic x-ray-phantom installation is big headache. Instead of this i found very realistic and easy solution for static+dynamic scrapping which is mentioned in https://pusher.com/tutorials/web-scraper-node

Comment: This module isn't new any more.

Answer (score 0):

Answering this as a canonical, an alternative to Puppeteer for scraping dynamic sites which is also well-supported as of 2023 is [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/). Here's a simple example:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright"); // ^1.28.1

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://example.com");
  const text = await page.locator('h1:text("Example")').textContent();
  console.log(text); // => Example Domain
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close());
```

---

Another approach is to [try accessing the API directly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66878732/6243352). The linked tutorial uses some Python, but most of the techniques apply equally to Node. I'll summarize them here. The high-level strategy is to search the network requests for your data to determine if it's being served by an unsecured API endpoint. If so, you can make a traditional HTTP request to download the raw JSON data directly.

In other cases, the data is available as a JS object or JSON string in `<script>` tags served with the static page. An HTML parser like Cheerio can then be used to extract the data, possibly with a bit of regex.

Usually, accessing the raw data will be faster, easier and more reliable than browser automation.

Answer (score 0):

Cheerios has the limitation that it will only return the raw HTML on the first visit.

Dynamic content or javascript-rendered content is indeed one of the challenges you'll face on web scraping.

The solution would be using a headless-browsers. This means we can interact with a website just like a real visitor.

Some samples for headless browsers for Javascript:

- [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/)
- [Playwright](https://playwright.dev/)

Here is a post on [web scraping with javascript](https://serpapi.com/blog/web-scraping-in-javascript-complete-tutorial-for-beginne) that highlights the difference between scraping a "static site" with Cheerio and a dynamic site with Puppeteer.

Another trick I should mention is looking at the external script that the website uses. Sometimes, the data you're looking for is available there. So you just have to request to this external script rather than running a headless-browser tech.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Nitpick: "Cheerios has the limitation that it will only return the raw HTML on the first visit" is a bit misleading--Cheerio only behaves this way if you use `fetch` or `axios` and make a single HTTP request to the static HTML. Cheerio doesn't execute JS, but this is really a consequence of the request library rather than the HTML parser, because if you plug Cheerio into Puppeteer, it can work on dynamic pages (not that it's a good idea to combine the two libs).

Answer (score -1):

Easiest and reliable solution is to use puppeteer. As mentioned in https://pusher.com/tutorials/web-scraper-node which is suitable for both static + dynamic **scraping**.

Only change the timeout in Browser.js, TimeoutSettings.js, Launcher.js 300000 to 3000000

Comment: This doesn't add much to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47202431/6243352) that already recommended Puppeteer.