# NodeJS Get Completely Rendered HTML Page

Tags: node.js, express

I want to get a html page content from a url using NodeJS after JavaScript is fully loaded and the page is completely rendered, or get the basic html then run all JavaScript files to achieve final content.
For example let's assume there is a website based on AngularJS, so the basic html is simple, but after loading all JavaScript codes in the page, page content is completely different. I want to get that final content on my server to find something in it. Any ideas?

Comment: You need something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) to do it. There is a plenty of wrappers for it on npm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739098/how-can-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamic-content-using-node-js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it's too late, but back in the day, PhantomJS solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

[After-Load](https://github.com/abdennour/node-afterload#readme) is a NodeJS package that works like a charm :

```
var afterLoad=require('after-load');
```

then :

```
afterLoad('http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366718',function(html){

       console.log(html.indexOf('charm')>0);
         //true 
})
```

Comment: The link is invalid. Do you have other link?

Comment: `https://www.npmjs.com/package/after-load` but it doesn't work on Windows...

Comment: really sorry! but i never consider Windows when I do programming ! really sorry