# how to get other domain body in browser (node)

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm new to node.
First I programmed a project that worked properly through console.
When I tried to make a web interface i faced different problems.
I used `request` npm package, when i tried to do so webpack won't import package to my project.
I tried to used different packages such as `browser-request` then i faced this message in console:

```
access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://google.com/' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

I use cheerio@1.0.0-rc.2 and after-load need cheerio 0.20.0 , can't use that npm package.

My question is how can i get response code and source body from a url that my web user fill in browser?

Any other proper way to do that?

Comment: Why `php` tag??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NodeJS Get Completely Rendered HTML Page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29366718/nodejs-get-completely-rendered-html-page)

Comment: @ventaqui cause php solution solve my problem

Answer (score 0):

You are probably dealing with [Cross-Origin Resource Sharing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issues when running from `localhost`.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10883211/deadly-cors-when-http-localhost-is-the-origin) for possible solutions.