# NodeJS - Delay "request" before getting the body?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Basically I'm getting the page I want using NodeJS, but it reads it too fast. The site I'm trying to read stuff from loads the divs (posts) that I want to read too slowly, so I get the body returned before the posts (that loads "dynamically"/after a second or so).

Not sure if I make any sense here but anyways.

```
var options = {
    url: array[i],
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13'
            }
}
request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if(!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
           console.log(body);
}
```

The body contains the webpage, but without the posts that takes a second or so to load.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you'll need to use a headless browser such as phantom.js since the JavaScript will not be executed and so dynamic content will not be loaded.

This thread might help:

[How can I scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739098/how-can-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamic-content-using-node-js)