# npm request wait before reading body

Tags: javascript, npm, npm-request

I am trying to use npm request and cheerio to pull webpages and parse their html. This works fine for cases where the html is loaded on request. But I am having an issue where the site loads a loading screen first and then updates the page with new info / elements after a few moments.

**Partial code:**

```
var url = 'website with loading screen prior to content.com';
var request = require('request');
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
  }
})
```

**What I would like**
 - Either request having the ability to wait for a specific element to show up on the page and then read the body. OR be able to wait a fixed number of seconds and then read the body

**Other options**
- It might not be possible with npm request, which is fine. If that is the case could you please point me in the correct direction. My other options that I am considering are using webdriver.io or phantomjs. Is there a recommended course of action for this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to configure `request` to "wait" after the request has been initiated before obtaining a response.  The best thing for you to do is to check out [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/).  It is a headless browser that you can use to load and render the page and then access dynamically generated content via javascript.

Check out this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739098/how-can-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamic-content-using-node-js) for a brief example.

Comment: Thanks, I had listed phantomjs as a possible option in my question. I actually ended up using it with some great success.