# Get data from webpage with cheerio

Tags: node.js, request, cheerio

I am trying to get the API response time from a website with cheerio. I have to wait first though for the site to fetch the time, though I am not sure how exactly to do that. Here is what I have tried. At the moment it does not work because it doesnt wait for the website to fetch the time.

```
request.get("site", function (err, res, body) {
    if (!err) {
      var $ = cheerio.load(body);
      $('.metrics-container').filter(function(){
        var data = $(this);
        var response_time_api = data.children().children().children()[1].children;
        console.log(response_time_api)
      });
    }
});
```

[here is the image from the source am fetching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5j4F.png)

Comment: You'll need to use something like phantomjs to scrape a site with its javascript executed

Comment: From what I know though, phantomjs doesnt really know when the page has loaded, so I have to set a time to wait eg: 1s even if the page takes 10ms correct? - though I guess the browser doesnt know as well so nothing to can be done about that.

Comment: Likely relevant: [How can I scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739098/how-can-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamic-content-using-node-js)