# PhantomJS Error: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, web-scraping, phantomjs

My goal is to scrape some data from a web site using [Node.js](https://nodejs.org).

I already managed to scrape data using only `request` package, but the site that I want scrape has dynamic content, and `request` only can't grab this dynamic data.

So I did some research and found that, to achieve that, and based in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739098/how-can-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamic-content-using-node-js), I would need to install some packages via `npm` (*I do not know if all three are needed*):

- [Request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request)
- [Cheerio](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cheerio)
- [Phantom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/phantom)

Based on the question too, I used the same code, just to understand how it works:

**myFile.js**

```
var phantom = require('phantom');

phantom.create(function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {
    var url = "http://www.bdtong.co.kr/index.php?c_category=C02";
    page.open(url, function() {
      page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
        page.evaluate(function() {
          $('.listMain > li').each(function () {
            console.log($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
          });
        }, function(){
          ph.exit()
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

But when I try to run in terminal `$ node myFile.js`, it don't work and keeps giving me the error:

> (node:6576) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Unexpected type of parameters. Expecting args to be array.
>
> (node:6576) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Any ideas how to solve this?

**EDIT:**

Final solution based on @Shyam answer (solved the error) and [this example](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/blob/master/examples/simple.js):

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
var _ph, _page, _outObj;

phantom
  .create()
  .then(ph => {
    _ph = ph;
    return _ph.createPage();
  })
  .then(page => {
    _page = page;
    return _page.open('https:/www.google.com.br/');
  })
  .then(status => {
    console.log(status);
    return _page.property('content');
  })
  .then(content => {
    console.log(content);
    _page.close();
    _ph.exit();
  })
  .catch(e => console.log(e))
;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure where you got the format from but the latest phantom JS does not use callbacks and uses promises instead. And the [constructor](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node#phantomcreate) (Phantom.create) expects configs in form of array and not a callback function.

Your code need's to be something similar to this I presume(I have not tested this but should run).

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
var _ph, _page;
phantom.create()
  .then(function (ph) {
    _ph = ph;
    return ph.createPage();
  })
  .then(function (page) {
    _page = page; 
    var url = "http://www.bdtong.co.kr/index.php?c_category=C02";
    return page.open(url);
  })
  .then(function(page) {
    page.includeJs("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js", function() {
      page.evaluate(function() {
        $('.listMain > li').each(function () {
          console.log($(this).find('a').attr('href'));
        });
      });
    });
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    _page.close();
    _ph.exit();
  })
```

Comment: I wasn't being able to get the result page with you solution, I was only receiving a string "success", but your code helped to show me the way to solve it, using [this example](https://github.com/amir20/phantomjs-node/blob/master/examples/simple.js) in github. Unfortunately I still wasn't able to get the dynamic content of the page, and is returning only the static content and the js functions, but this is not part of this question. Thank you!

Comment: for page evaluate you should resolve the promise to get the result (page evaluate is promise method)

```page.evaluate(function() {
       return document.title;
      }).then(function(title){
 console.log("Page Title", title);
})```