# Web scraping google search page with nodejs and cheerio

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I am having problems scraping a google search page. I can scrape a normal web page but the same code does not work on a search page

I am using nodejs with cheerio api. The search page is for the "restaurants near me". Here is the code

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');

request('https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS795US795&q=restaurants+near+me&npsic=0&rflfq=1&rlha=0&rllag=43556429,-83953443,247&tbm=lcl&ved=2ahUKEwikkKDVhvPcAhUEmuAKHekOBl4QjGp6BAgDEE8&tbs=lrf:!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e5!2m1!1e1!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:9&rldoc=1#rlfi=hd:;si:;mv:!1m3!1d37687.821017182374!2d-83.91493835!3d43.58986!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i324!2i313!4f13.1;tbs:lrf:!2m1!1e2!2m1!1e5!2m1!1e1!2m1!1e3!3sIAE,lf:1,lf_ui:9',(error,response,html)=>{
  if(!error && response.statusCode==200){
    const $= cheerio.load(html)

    $(".dbg0pd").each(function(i, element){
      var a = $(this);
      console.log('This is from inside the loop')
      console.log(a.text());
    });

  }
})
```

In the web page, running inspect element shows that the class `dbg0pd` contains the `div` element which contains the name of the restaurant. However the `.each()` jquery loop does not even fire as my test console.log statement does not print *This is from inside the loop*

Running `node scrape.js` does not print anything.

Comment: I tried manually pulling the page from Google and then doing your cheerio logic, and could not replicate your problem.  Make sure you're not getting an error or non-200 response.

Comment: If I do `console.log($)` it will display the cheerio object. I do not have any response error. Did you use the same url as me?

Comment: Yes, copied from your question, but I pulled it through the browser, which in the past Google has blocked scraper type software to its browser friendly URLs.  It does offer a search API that alleviates the need for scraping, though.

Comment: I changed the search parameter to search all the div elements instead of that class.I feel like I cannot use cheerio on google search page because when I tried to scrape a url that was displaying restaurants using the code above it returns divs like Images, Vidoes, Maps etc but instead of the resturants I got this at the end

 _did not match any documents. Reset search toolsSuggestions:Make sure all words are spelled correctly.Try different keywords.Try more general keywords.Try fewer keywords_

Comment: Do you have any recommendation for a search api?

Comment: Depending on your needs: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview

Comment: If you `console.log(html)` you'll see the selector and HTML aren't present. You're probably being detected as a bot.

Comment: Looking at it a few months later, `dbg0pd` doesn't appear in the static HTML and neither do restaurant names, so I think [How can I scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739098/how-can-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamic-content-using-node-js) applies.