# Node.js Web Crawling - How to get all data loaded in HTML?

Tags: html, node.js, web-crawler

I am trying to use Node.js to implement Data Scrawling. I used axios to GET HTML file and use cheerio to get data.

However, I found that the HTML doesn't return with data but only layout. I guess the website with load the layout first, then doing ajax things to query data then rendering.

So, Anyone know how to GET the full HTML with data? Any library or tools?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739098/how-can-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamic-content-using-node-js)

Comment: There are various questions about that topic here on StackOverflow. And also many sites targeting exactly that topic. All have in common that they use/suggest a fully featured browser engine to load the page.

Answer (score 0):

i would suggest you to use selenium library with bs4 library in python if have some experience on python.

for node

> https://www.npmjs.com/package/selenium-webdriver

i have written **scraper** in python using both library.

**scraper** is for linked in profile which take name from excel file and search if data available add it into another excel file

```
https://github.com/harsh4870/Scraper_LinkedIn
```

for node code goes like

```
    driver = webdriver.Firefox();
driver.get("http://example.com");
html = driver.getPageSource();
```