# cheerioJS not grabbing element from page

Tags: web-scraping, cheerio

I'm having issues grabbing an element with cheerio js.

I opened the following website -> https://www.voobly.com/ladder/view/Age-of-Mythology-The-Titans/1v1-Supremacy

and when I do view page source I can see the id -> pagebrowser1, but when I try to grab it using cheerio, it returns null.

[image]

[image]

```
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');

axios.get('https://www.voobly.com/ladder/view/Age-of-Mythology-The-Titans/1v1-Supremacy').then((res) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(res.data)    

    console.log($("#pagebrowser1").html());
});
```

Comment: They're likely blocking you because you're not sending a user-agent header

Comment: I'm still having no luck, does it work for you? If so, can you show the code.

Comment: I just realized what you said, that page that i'm trying to access, requires me to login, don't think cherrio js has a solution for it, I'm going to use nightmare js proxy for this problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739098/how-can-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamic-content-using-node-js)