# How to get value with cheerio on node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

How to get **IMVALUE** on source code like that with cheerio on node.js?

**Element/View Source:**

```
<div class="e7m mess_bodiyy">
  <p style="max-width: 600px">
    Hello x7907062441,
    <br />
    <br />
    This is the value:
    <br />
    <a href="http://mywebsite.com" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">
      IMVALUE
    </a>
    .<br />
    <br />
  </p>
</div>
```

I've tried with

```js
const src = $('<div class="e7m mess_bodiyy"></div>').
```

But the result is undefined.

Comment: `$('<div class="e7m mess_bodiyy"></div>')` is creating a new div element, not selecting any existing elements.  `$('.e7m.mess_bodiyy')` would be selecting existing elements

Comment: @Taplar so the code will be const src = $('.e7m.mess_bodiyy').text()
That's right?

Because the response is blank

Comment: Or `.html()`, yes

Comment: @Taplar but the result is blank, when i try to use .html() the response is null

Comment: `console.log($('.e7m').length)` and see what it logs

Comment: @Taplar the result is: "79"

Comment: Woah, ok, what about with the selector of `.e7m.mess_bodiyy`?

Comment: @Taplar when i change to .e7m.mess_bodiyy the response is "0"

Comment: Alright, so that's saying at the time that you run that selector, no element matches that criteria

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205259/discussion-between-hacking-to-win-and-taplar).

Comment: Make sure that the html content didn't rendered by client side.

Answer (score 0):

Terminology technicality: that's *text*, not a *value*.

This is a value (it's a specific attribute):

```html
<input value="some value">
```

(You can get that with `$("input").val()` or select it with `$('[value="some value"]')`)

This is text:

```html
<p>some text</p>
```

(You get that with `$("p").text()`)

---

You don't select and traverse CSS by passing in the HTML. If you wanted to do a substring check like that you can do so on plain strings, without Cheerio. But this isn't useful since in HTML, we want to disregard whitespace and the order of attributes. With strings, it's extremely difficult to determine which elements are ancestors of other elements. Cheerio parses the string into a tree that CSS selectors traverse, solving these problems.

Let's use Cheerio with a CSS selector on your string:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `<Your HTML>`;
const $ = cheerio.load(html);
console.log($(".e7m.mess_bodiyy a").text().trim()); // => IMVALUE
```

This selector says "find the `<a>` element that's some descendant of an element with the classes `e7m` and `mess_bodiyy` in any order".

---

Now, based on the discussion, if this doesn't log anything, maybe you're getting the HTML from the browser developer tools, which includes elements injected after page load by JavaScript. If you're doing a simple HTTP request to retrieve the static HTML, you may not see the same elements which are visible in dev tools. If this is the case, you'll need a different tool than Cheerio such as Puppeteer. See [How can I scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739098/how-can-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamic-content-using-node-js) for details.