# Scrape dynamic websites with cheerio and nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm beginner with cheerio, trying to implement a simple example to learn more about it. tried some solutions on Stackoverflow without success, for the beginning tried it on google website, just for my learn, marked the element I want with yellow, help some1 please?

my code:

```
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const request = require('request');

request({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://www.google.co.il/'
}, (err, res, body) => {

    if (err) return console.error(err);

    let $ = cheerio.load(body);

    $('div[class="gb_h gb_i"]').find('a').each(function (index, element) {
        console.log(element.attr(href));
      });

});
```

the elements in google:

[image]

Comment: If it's not on the dom, when you do `view-source:https://www.google.co.il/` then cheerio is no use, your need to use something like puppeteer instead

Comment: Thanks mate, helped me alot ! <3

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739098/how-can-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamic-content-using-node-js)