# Cheerio just shows the first item instead of the list of children in div

Tags: node.js, cheerio

I'm trying to get all items in a specific `div` that is already addressed.

But after using `children()` it only shows the **first** item instead of a **list** of whole children.

Here is the source:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
> const html = res.data;
> const $ = cheerio.load(html);
> const data = $('div[id="thepics"]');
> console.log(data);
```

And its result:

```
LoadedCheerio {
  '0': <ref *1> Node {
    type: 'tag',
    name: 'div',
    namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
    attribs: [Object: null prototype] {
      style: 'margin:-5px 0px 10px 0px',
      id: 'thepics'
    },
    'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype] { style: undefined, id: undefined },
    'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype] { style: undefined, id: undefined },
    children: [ [Node] ],
    parent: Node {
      type: 'tag',
      name: 'div',
      namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
      attribs: [Object: null prototype],
      'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype],
      'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype],
      children: [Array],
      parent: [Node],
      prev: [Node],
      next: [Node]
    },
    prev: Node {
      type: 'tag',
      name: 'div',
      namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
      attribs: [Object: null prototype],
      'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype],
      'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype],
      children: [],
      parent: [Node],
      prev: [Node],
      next: [Circular *1]
    },
    next: Node {
      type: 'tag',
      name: 'div',
      namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
      attribs: [Object: null prototype],
      'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype],
      'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype],
      children: [Array],
      parent: [Node],
      prev: [Circular *1],
      next: [Node]
    }
  },
  length: 1,
  options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
  _root: <ref *2> LoadedCheerio {
    '0': Node {
      type: 'root',
      name: 'root',
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null,
      children: [Array],
      'x-mode': 'no-quirks'
    },
    length: 1,
    options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
    _root: [Circular *2]
  },
  prevObject: <ref *2> LoadedCheerio {
    '0': Node {
      type: 'root',
      name: 'root',
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null,
      children: [Array],
      'x-mode': 'no-quirks'
    },
    length: 1,
    options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
    _root: [Circular *2]
  }
}
```

And after try to log `data.children()` the result is:

```
LoadedCheerio {
  '0': Node {
    type: 'script',
    name: 'script',
    namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
    attribs: [Object: null prototype] {},
    'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype] {},
    'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype] {},
    children: [ [Node] ],
    parent: Node {
      type: 'tag',
      name: 'div',
      namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
      attribs: [Object: null prototype],
      'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype],
      'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype],
      children: [Array],
      parent: [Node],
      prev: [Node],
      next: [Node]
    },
    prev: null,
    next: null
  },
  length: 1,
  options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
  _root: <ref *1> LoadedCheerio {
    '0': Node {
      type: 'root',
      name: 'root',
      parent: null,
      prev: null,
      next: null,
      children: [Array],
      'x-mode': 'no-quirks'
    },
    length: 1,
    options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
    _root: [Circular *1]
  },
  prevObject: LoadedCheerio {
    '0': Node {
      type: 'tag',
      name: 'div',
      namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
      attribs: [Object: null prototype],
      'x-attribsNamespace': [Object: null prototype],
      'x-attribsPrefix': [Object: null prototype],
      children: [Array],
      parent: [Node],
      prev: [Node],
      next: [Node]
    },
    length: 1,
    options: { xml: false, decodeEntities: true },
    _root: <ref *1> LoadedCheerio {
      '0': [Node],
      length: 1,
      options: [Object],
      _root: [Circular *1]
    },
    prevObject: <ref *1> LoadedCheerio {
      '0': [Node],
      length: 1,
      options: [Object],
      _root: [Circular *1]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share the site you're scraping. The "source" you've shown appears to be the browser's element inspector, which is something else. Those elements may well have been injected with JS after the page load, in which case cheerio wouldn't see them in the static HTML you've retrieved.

Comment: `$('div[id="thepics"] div.pic')` -- that is how you would get the children divs.

Comment: @ggorlen yes it uses JS after the page load. In this case, what is the best solution instead of cheerio? If cheerio cannot read it anymore.

Comment: It depends on the site. Sometimes you can use their API, other times there's JSON baked into the static HTML as a script, sometimes you need Selenium/Puppeteer. See [How can I scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739098/how-can-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamic-content-using-node-js)

Comment: Voting to close again a year later--there's no [mcve] or site, so there's no value to future visitors or possible answer to be had here.