# Google Apps Script: How to scrape a dynamic website table data with Cheerio?

Tags: web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to scrape GDP data from [BEA website](https://apps.bea.gov/iTable/iTable.cfm?reqid=19&step=3&isuri=1&nipa_table_list=5&categories=survey).  The following codes returned empty.  Can anyone help out what should be changed in the codes?  Thanks!

```
function test() {
  const url = 'https://apps.bea.gov/iTable/iTable.cfm?reqid=19&step=3&isuri=1&nipa_table_list=5&categories=survey';
  var res = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, { muteHttpExceptions: true }).getContentText();
  var $ = Cheerio.load(res);
  var table = $("#tbl_wrapper").find('td').toArray().map(el => $(el).text());
  console.log(table)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried download the table as CSV instead? Seems like that would be easier.

Comment: I know it.  But what I wanted is to automate the scraping as I deal with a lot of data mining.  Seems like the cheerio can’t handle such a dynamic website that I’m lacking a basic skill.

Comment: Cheerio can handle it just fine you just need to invest a bit of reverse engineering skills. However, it's much easier to reverse engineer how the download button works and replicate that in your script instead.

Comment: If the data comes from an xhr you can just load that, otherwise you want a browser like puppeteer.

Comment: Try moving `.toArray()` after `.map()`, so it looks like this `.map().toArray();`

Comment: It didn’t help.   I have many other applications working well with .toArray().map().  I wonder if you tested it out.

Comment: Hi @Tanaike, I learned a lot of web scraping codes from you.  Can I ask you again for your help in this post?   Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739098/how-can-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamic-content-using-node-js)

Comment: @ggorlen, I’m looking for a solution in Google Apps Script or JavaScript, which isn’t covered in your suggested post.  Anyway thank you for a future reference.

Comment: You might want to [edit] this post to clarify that. The concept is the same though: you're trying to interact with a dynamic JS-driven site with a static HTML parser that only traverses a plain HTML string.