# How to stop divs from hidding when scrolling

Tags: javascript, html, events, dom-events

I have been collecting product prices for a market investigation project in my University. So far I have been looking at very basic pages or forms where I could extract every product´s name and price with a simple js, but I have encountered many pages like [this one](https://vivetmarket.com/app/products), where upon scrolling there is an event listener that updates the html to only have the code of the products the user can see.
My knowledge in javascript is not this advanced, and I can´t figure out how to make the html show all divs at the same time, so I can then extract them with one script.

Comment: Basically what the sites do is to cache data and to dynamically generate the content. There is no way for you to extract all at once an easy way. Easiest possible solution would be to get access to the database and extract a jason of all the entries

Comment: Related question: [How can I scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739098/how-can-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamic-content-using-node-js)

Answer (score -1):

Try to use **Position: Sticky** in your css file

Comment: This is lightyears from what the question here is actually about. They do not want to _build_ or style a site, they want to fetch data from an already existing site.