# how to make web-scraping using cheerio

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I've tried this code

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require('axios');

async function getProducts() {
  try{
    
    const res = await axios.get('https://www.carrefouruae.com/mafuae/en/v4/search?keyword=tomato%20kathcup');
    const html = await res.data;
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    const products = [];
    $('ul[data-testid]').each((i, el) => {
      const title = $(el).find('a[data-testid="product_name"]').text().trim();
      const price = $(el).find('div[data-testid="product_price"] .css-fzp91j').text().trim();
      products.push({ title, price });
    });

    console.log(products);
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
};

getProducts();
```

I need the product list array containing title and price but this code returning me empty array. What to do for getting these details? Example link: `https://www.carrefouruae.com/mafuae/en/v4/search?keyword=tomato%20kathcup`.

Amazon work but this carefour website not working for web scraping!

```
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const axios = require('axios');

async function getProducts() {
  try{
    
    const res = await axios.get('https://www.carrefouruae.com/mafuae/en/v4/search?keyword=tomato%20kathcup');
    const html = await res.data;
    const $ = cheerio.load(html);

    const products = [];
    $('ul[data-testid]').each((i, el) => {
      const title = $(el).find('a[data-testid="product_name"]').text().trim();
      const price = $(el).find('div[data-testid="product_price"] .css-fzp91j').text().trim();
      products.push({ title, price });
    });

    console.log(products);
  }catch(err){
    console.log(err)
  }
};

getProducts();
```

Tried this and expecting to get details and price of products using cheerio- Nodejs

Comment: The page is JS-driven, so `product_name` doesn't appear in the HTML returned by axios. Try Puppeteer or Playwright.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I scrape pages with dynamic content using node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28739098/how-can-i-scrape-pages-with-dynamic-content-using-node-js)

Comment: @ggorlen I wan't able to find out the product_name using puppeteer. Could you please make a scraping code for https://www.carrefouruae.com/mafuae/en/v4/search?keyword=tomato%20kathcup

Comment: If you post your attempt as a new question, I'll see it and try to answer it. You could also [edit] this one since nobody has answered it.

Answer (score 0):

Replying to an old question, but if you don't want to use puppeteer, you can still get the data from this site *(and such others)* if they have their data on every page in JSON format within script tags, this site has it in `<script id="__NEXT_DATA__">...</script>`,

For products on multiple pages, look at the URL, in this case, a **Load More** button appears when there are too many products to display, and clicking on it changes the url from

```
https://www.carrefouruae.com/mafuae/en/v4/search?keyword=still%20water
```

to

```
https://www.carrefouruae.com/mafuae/en/v4/search?currentPage=1&filter=&keyword=still%20water&pageSize=60&sortBy=relevance
```

the rest is get the page add products to array until no product data is returned.

```js
const axios = require('axios');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');
let fsp = fs.promises;

(async () => {

    async function getProducts(keyword, page = 0) {
        try {
            let all = [];
            let url = `https://www.carrefouruae.com/mafuae/en/v4/search?currentPage=${page}&filter=&keyword=${encodeURI(keyword)}&pageSize=60&sortBy=relevance`

            const response = await axios.get(url);
            const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);

            let raw = $('script#__NEXT_DATA__').text();
            let parsed = JSON.parse(raw);
            let products = parsed.props.initialState.search.products; // take a look here to see other fields that you can get, add them to the return below.

            products = products.map( x => {
                return {
                    name : x.name,
                    brand : x.brand,
                    size : x.size,
                    price : x.originalPrice,
                    currency : x.currency,
                    discount : x.discount,
                    url : x.url,
                    image : x.image.href,
                    otherImages : x.imageLibrary.map(el => el.href),
                    min : x.min,
                    max : x.max,  
                    origin : x.productOrigin,                 
                    supplier : x.supplier                    
                }
            });

            if (products.length != 0) { // page still returning products continue
                all.push(products);
                all = [...all, ...(await getProducts(keyword, page+1))].flat(); 
            } 

            // write everything to JSON file, 
            const data = JSON.stringify(all, null, 2); 
            await fsp.writeFile('searchResults.json', data);

            return all;
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error);
        }
    }

let result = await getProducts('still water');

console.log(result);
console.log(result.length); // check last product manually as the site displays a wrong product count.

})().catch(err => console.error(err));
```