# How can I use Node / Cheerio (or something else) to scrape a global variable from a site?

Tags: node.js, express, web-scraping, cheerio

There is a global variable on a page that contains an object that I'd like to set up a scraper for. What's the best way to do this with Node / Express / potentially Cheerio?

I understand Cheerio's benefit in traversing a DOM, but I know the name of the global variable I want to scrape and just need to extract its information on a set schedule

Comment: What is a "global variable on a page"? you mean a javascript variable in the code inserted in the page?

Comment: Yeah. There is a global variable on a website which is an object. If I go to this site and enter that variable name into my console, it returns the object I want. Is there a way with Node I can scrape that variable?

Comment: Please show the page. If the variable is raw in a `<script>` tag it may be possible to parse with a plain HTTP request and Cheerio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cheerio is just a dom parser, so you wont have acces to any javascriot or any javascript generated content.

What you need is something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) that simulates a browser.
Have a look at this [Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18831566/4247467)